# Nested loop in a dictionnary template django

Tags: python, django, templates

In my view.py, my context look like this:

```
  context = {'books': books, 'asked_author': asked_author, 'role':  role_field_list}
```

books is a list of dictionary (a list of book) and for each book, it exists one or more keys for which the key is named by a name in role_field_list:

I try to execute this template:

```
{% for book in books %}
    {% for name in role %}
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
        {% for authors in book.name %}
            {{ authors.lastname }} {{authors.firstname}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But book.name doesn't worked.
It takes name as a litteral 'name' not as a variable...

Thank you for any help.

To have more details about "field" and "type" of my context dictionnary, this my view.py:

```
def booksAuthor(request, author):
    books_role = AuthorRoleBook.objects.filter(author_book=author).values() # get all the books written by one author
    asked_author = AuthorBook.objects.get(pk=author) # get lastname and firstname for the author selected
    books=[]
    for book_role in books_role:
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_role['book_id'])
        book_dict = model_to_dict(book)
        authors_role =  AuthorRoleBook.objects.filter(book_id=book).values() # Get id of the different contributor for each book
        role_field_list = ['auteur', 'traducteur', 'editeur_scientifique', 'directeur_publication']
        for name in role_field_list:
            list_author=[]
            for author_role in authors_role:
                if author_role['role_id']==name:
                     author=AuthorBook.objects.get(pk=author_role['author_book_id'])
                     author_dict = model_to_dict(author)
                     list_author.append(author_dict)
                else:
                    pass
            book_dict[name]=list_author
        books.append(book_dict)
        print(book_dict)
        context = {'books': books, 'asked_author': asked_author, 'role': role_field_list}
    return render(request, 'books_author.html', context)
```

And for my models, maybe it is not the easier way but this is:

```
class AuthorRoleBook(models.Model):
     author_book = models.ForeignKey(AuthorBook)
     role = models.ForeignKey('Role')
     book = models.ForeignKey('Book')

class AuthorBook(models.Model):
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    .... ....
    unique_together = (('lastname', 'firstname'),)

class Role(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    titre = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
     .......  ....   ...
    isbn_electronique = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, the way you are doing it you will print all the books for every role in the list and that may not be what you want. Second of all, there's no such variable `book` in your context, you are passing `books` instead. Elaborate your question, show some more code.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? A lot of the code you've included in your view looks outdated.. Could you also include the models code regarding their relationships?

Comment: @mathieu - And am I right in thinking you're trying to get a list of books for a certain author?

Comment: Yes. I try to have a list of book for a "certain author". And after for each book I try to have the differents contributors, traductor, authors also... which have participed to this book (including the "certain author" of course).

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working now. I keep the same views.py but in my template I do this:

```
{% for book in books %}
    <h4>{{ book.titre }}</h4>
    {% if book.directeur_publication %}
        Directeur Publication:
        {% for name in book.directeur_publication %}
            {{ name.lastname }} {{name.firstname}}
        {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
     {% if book.editeur_scientifique %} ....
```

...
.....Etc

And for each value in role_field_list (['auteur', 'traducteur', 'editeur_scientifique', 'directeur_publication']) I put manually the value n my template in a "if condition".

It is not really a beautiful way... but it is working. For sure to use model object and not dictionary will be better.
Thanks for your answer, nevertheless if you have a smart code or idea to do that...